# C# .NET Xml Serialization - wrong encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, encoding

I am creating new version of old software (written in different language) which must be compatible, and more precisely export and import should work between them.

Old soft XML file in notepad++:
[original xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntZAU.png)

My XML created in C# also in notepad++:
[new xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIPwC.png)

Code to generate this XML:

```
        XAttribute rootName = new XAttribute("Name", "");
        XElement root = new XElement("Template", rootName);

        root.Add(new XElement("CODE", "JP„"));

        var document = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", "yes"), root);
        document.Save("C:\\temp\\Test.xml");
```

The special character in my xml is encoded incorrect. It makes me dizzy, because it should be in ISO-8859-1 encoding, even notepad++ shows that file has this encoding.

How can I force my XML to treat special characters like the old one?

Comment: Writing should be no issue.  The reading is an issue because the Net library doesn't accept the Identification line with ISO-8859-1.  So I usually just open the file with StreamReader.  Then read one line and feed stream to Load Method like this : StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("filename"); reader.ReadLine(); XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

Comment: Can you share the actual XML rather than a screenshot of it?  See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for why.

Answer (score 0):

The „ character is not represented in iso-8859-1 so you have no way to write it to a 8859-1 encoded file.

Your old program writes some byte after JP but it's only some non-defined behaviour what is specific to your old language/application. IND is a control character, not a 8859-1 character.
XDocument does the best it can: writes the unicode code point with character representation. (Your program code is in utf8, I guess, so the „ is represented in your program in utf8.)

I guess, you should investigate what your old program does and mimic it by hand. For example, you could create a mapping that assigns every possible non-8859-1 character to a valid 8859-1 character.